# How to create a new Line when merging Content Controls with XML using Docx4J?

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

Is there a way to create a new line in the resulting docx file which we get when merged docx template with xml using Docx4J as shown in this [example](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlsMergeXML.java).

Considering that I want multiple lines in an docx file but I am passing those lines via XML element through the XML file which I will be merging with the docx file, how do I create a new line for a particular set of words present in the XML element when the same is merged with the docx template?

For reference --> Example XML data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UtF-8" standalone="yes"  ?>
<ChargesInvoice>
    <invoicedate>05/01/2016</invoicedate>
    <vatnumber>GB 123456789</vatnumber>
    <dealercode>123456789</dealercode>
    <intenralcontact>956532456987321</intenralcontact>
    <invoicenumber>qwertyuiop</invoicenumber>

    <invoicedetails>
        <invoice>
            <Description>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            </Description>
            <NettAmount>300</NettAmount>
            <VATRate>30%</VATRate>
            <VATAmount>30</VATAmount>
            <GrossAmount>310</GrossAmount>
        </invoice>
        <invoice>
            <Description>apak</Description>
            <NettAmount>220</NettAmount>
            <VATRate>12%</VATRate>
            <VATAmount>24.4</VATAmount>
            <GrossAmount>234.4</GrossAmount>
        </invoice>
    </invoicedetails>
</ChargesInvoice>
```

As we can see above that there is more data present in the invoice element and I want to display a part of it in a new line. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

BindingTraverserXSLT should insert br elements in place of the following tokens:

```
    // tokenize on the newline character, the carriage-return character, 
    // and the form-feed character
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(r, "\n\r\f");
```

Alternatively, it can convert escaped Flat OPC XML or XHTML, though some setup is involved.